# C#. Регулярное выражение по выделению hex части числа из строки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте есть строка вида  "0x05 0x12 25 папвапавп 0х10оророро";

Нужно все подстроки которые начинаются на 0x и дальше 2 символа в hex игнорировать и выделять только остальные строки.
Этот pattern буду использовать в функции

```
Regex.Replace(template, pattern, Evaluator)
```

чтобы выделенные подстроки превратить в массив байт в определенной кодировке.

Должны быть выделены следующие строки (пробел заменяю на _):

```
 1._
 2._25_папвапавп_
 3.оророро
```

Мне нужно чтобы в Evaluator попадали нужные строки

```
    public static string StringTemplateInsert(string template, string pattern = @"0x[0-9A-F]{2}") 
    {
        string Evaluator(Match match)
        {
            string res;
            res = match.Groups[1].Value;
            return res;
        }

        var result = Regex.Replace(template, pattern, Evaluator);
        return result;
    }
```

Попытаюсь более точно описать задачу:
нужно в строке вида "0x05 0x12 25 папвапавп 0х10оророро"
заменить все подстроки на байтовое представление в кодировке "ср866" кроме строк попадающих под паттерн 0xYY, где YY 1 байт в HEX.

"0x05090x12"  => "05303912"
05 и 12 остались без измененния, отбросив только 0x.   09 преобразовалось в 2 байта в кодировке ср866

Comment: `Regex.Split(input, @"0x[0-9A-F]{2}")`

Comment: Split работает, но мне нужно чтобы строки попадали в метод Evaluator. Я подправил вопрос

Comment: есть регулярка которая выделяет из hex значимую часть                              @"(?i)\b0x([a-f0-9]+)\b" , может ее можно инвертировать чтобы выделялись другие строки?

Comment: Что мешает после Split пройтись по массиву и вызывать нужный метод для каждого элемента?

Comment: Напишите лучше свою реальную задачу, что вам в итоге надо получить?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: 1. Сплитим по указанной маске, для каждой строки в массиве выполняем посимвольное преобразование. 2. Захватываем по указанной маске и для каждой строки удаляем 0x. 3. Собираем из двух массивов обратно строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется непременно с Replace, то можно как-то так:

```
var template = "0x05090x12";// "0x05 0x12 25 папвапавп 0х10оророро";
var pattern = @"0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|.";
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);

string Evaluator(Match match)
{
    if (match.Value.StartsWith("0x")) // if (match.Value.Length == 4)
        return match.Value.Substring(2);
    else
        return enc.GetBytes(match.Value)[0].ToString("x");
}

var result = Regex.Replace(template, pattern, Evaluator);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

В шаблоне матчится или `0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}` (шестнадцатеричные числа) или `.` (любой символ). В евалюаторе выполняются действия в зависимости от найденного шаблона.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что в шаблоне можно задавть ИЛИ. я по такой логике и хотел сделать. На тестовой строке "0x080x11   0x03160x3A59" выдает "0811202020033136307833413539", а надо "08112020200331363A3539". Походу что-то лишнее попадается в math

Comment: Я уже написал свой вариант разбора,  где как в студентческом задании разложил строку на массив char, и обработал ее. Подскажите вариант с Регулярками будет медленнее чем разбор массива char?

Comment: @Aldmi - сложно сказать, что быстрее. Но в общем, регулярки весьма медленные.

Comment: @Aldmi - я исправил шаблон регулярки. Вместо `\d\d`, что матчит только десятичные цифры, нужно матчить шестнадцатеричные: `[0-9a-fA-F]{2}`.